# How would I create a 'rootfs.tar' of CentOS 7.1905 for use with 'wsl --import'?

Tags: centos7, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dnf

**1. Summarize the problem**

How would I create a **rootfs.tar** of **CentOS 7.1905** for use with `wsl --import` (**Windows Subsystem for Linux**)

I have not found a **rootfs.tar** file I can download of **CentOS 7.1905** in order to use with `wsl --import`.

I would like to be able to roll my own **rootfs.tar** using the **dnf** command, I have spent the evening searching, trying various things.

If anyone has built a **rootfs.tar** file for use with **WSL**, please post.

**mkosi** (ubuntu utilility) does not work, it cannot be used to build centos images, try it.

Downloading the **.raw.tar.gz** file does not work with `wsl --import`, try it.

I am attempting the following command in a **Windows .bat** file, but cannot find a suitable **rootfs.tar** file to use, or find a way to build one.

**File: create-rootfs.bat**

```
rem <DistributionName> <InstallLocation> <FileName>
wsl --import centos_7.6.1905 c:\wsl\centos\7.6.1905 g:\downloads\cent\centos\rootfs.tar
```

---

**2. Provide background including what you've already tried.**

I have spent the evening reading documentation, trying various incantations of **dnf** with no luck.  There are no examples out there, there are places where **dnf** and **mkosi** are recommended, and links to those, but there are no actual, concrete examples that work.

---

**4.  Describe expected and actual results including any error messages.**

I would like to build a **rootfs.tar** file of **CentOS 7.6.1905**, for use with `wsl --import`.

I am looking for actual examples that work, that have been tried, and proven.

Answer (score 3):

Here we can make CentOS rootfs tarball ourselves. It will be easier if you have a real Linux distribution installed in machine. But here we download a ready-made docker tarball (tar.xz) and convert it to tar.gz because WSL uses `bsdtar` to extract and install distributions. For this procedure, there should be a pre-installed distribution in WSL. Run that distribution and follow these steps as root user in `/root` folder to intact file permissions.

- Open this [CentOS docker](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images.git) git repository, go to latest CentOS version branch (not the master), download the `centos-7-docker.tar.xz` file.
- Repackage the XZ archive into a GZIP archive: `xz -d -c centos-7-docker.tar.xz | gzip -c -2 > centos-7-docker.tar.gz`
- Move that tar.gz folder to Windows drive: `mv test.tar.gz /mnt/c/MyFolder`
- Import that tar.gz file as a new distribution: `wsl.exe --import CentOS MyFolder test.tar.gz`
- Verify the distribution was installed: `wsl.exe --list -v`
- Start the container and log into it: `wsl.exe -d CentOS`

`dnf` is not installed in this docker file. So, use `rpm` or `yum` to install it, `yum install dnf`. Make sure Windows Firewall does not block it. For more distributions, you can see my [WslInstall](https://github.com/Biswa96/WSLInstall) repository.

Comment: I do not have a machine to install CentOS on, to create a tarball, I'm hoping this method will be the same, I will give it a try.  Thank you.

Comment: This solution will not, is not working for me, 

I'm not seeing 7.6.1905 on any branch, only 7.6.1810 as the latest.

I am seeking a way, instructions to build a 7.6.1905 .tar to use with `wsl --import`  I 'm not seeing the 1905 release in WslInstall repository.  Thank you.

Comment: This started with a .xz file, how was that point reached? 

Is that the best path to create a rootfs.tar for use with `wsl --import`?

Thank You

Comment: For a dry run, I tried release 1810 (ultimately seeking 1905), and got these error messages when trying to create the `tar.gz`.
```
tar: etc/gshadow: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: etc/gshadow-: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: etc/shadow: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: etc/shadow-: Cannot open: Permission denied
```
Is this important? If so, how to avoid when creating the `.tar.gz`?

Comment: I said to do it in `/root` as a root user. And I didn't find that version in [CentOS release notes](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes). Also you can bootstrap a newer version (if needed) from an older one.

Comment: I will give this a try again.

Comment: 2020-Sep-17

I still can not get this to work as described above

I followed the instructions exactly and get: error: 'user not found', no 'root' user

and I cannot create a 'root' user or any other user with any wsl.exe command

From a DOS cmd prompt, using:
wsl.exe --user root -d CentOS8

(will not enter a bash shell, get error, then back to cmd prompt)

I downloaded and used:
https://cloud.centos.org/centos/8/x86_64/images/CentOS-8-Container-8.2.2004-20200611.2.x86_64.tar.xz

as the git repo listed in the above was empty

Comment: works perfectly for me, from the first try

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to convert the CentOS cloud QCOW2 images to a rootfs.tar.gz.

Such QCOW2 images are found here: https://cloud.centos.org/centos/

Here is an example script that performs the conversion (requires `qemu-utils` to be installed):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Environment variables for the CentOS cloud image
ARCH="x86_64"
OS_VER="7"
ROOTFS_VER="2003"
ROOTFS_FN="CentOS-${OS_VER}-${ARCH}-GenericCloud-${ROOTFS_VER}.qcow2"
ROOTFS_URL="http://cloud.centos.org/centos/${OS_VER}/images/${ROOTFS_FN}"

# Environment variables for Yuk7's wsldl
LNCR_BLD="20040300"
LNCR_ZIP="icons.zip"
LNCR_NAME="CentOS"
LNCR_FN=${LNCR_NAME}.exe
LNCR_ZIPFN=${LNCR_NAME}${OS_VER}.exe
LNCR_URL="https://github.com/yuk7/wsldl/releases/download/${LNCR_BLD}/${LNCR_ZIP}"

# Waits until a file appears or disappears
# - $1   File path to wait for its existence
# - [$2] The string 'a' to wait until the file appears, or 'd' to wait until the file disappears
# - [$3] Timeout in seconds
waitFile() {
  local START=$(cut -d '.' -f 1 /proc/uptime)
  local MODE=${2:-"a"}
  until [[ "${MODE}" = "a" && -e "$1" ]] || [[ "${MODE}" = "d" && ( ! -e "$1" ) ]]; do
    sleep 1s
    if [ -n "$3" ]; then
      local NOW=$(cut -d '.' -f 1 /proc/uptime)
      local ELAPSED=$(( NOW - START ))
      if [ $ELAPSED -ge "$3" ]; then break; fi
    fi
  done
}

# Create a work dir
mkdir wsl
cd wsl

# Download the CentOS cloud image and Yuk7's WSLDL
wget --no-verbose ${ROOTFS_URL} -O ${ROOTFS_FN}
wget --no-verbose ${LNCR_URL} -O ${LNCR_ZIP}

# Extract the CentOS WSL launcher
unzip ${LNCR_ZIP} ${LNCR_FN}

# Clean up
rm ${LNCR_ZIP}

# Mount the qcow2 image
sudo mkdir mntfs
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 --read-only ./${ROOTFS_FN}
waitFile /dev/nbd0p1 "a" 30
sudo mount -o ro /dev/nbd0p1 mntfs

# Clone the qcow2 image contents to a writable directory
sudo cp -a mntfs rootfs

# Unmount the qcow2 image
sudo umount mntfs
sudo qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
waitFile /dev/nbd0p1 "d" 30
sudo rmmod nbd
sudo rmdir mntfs

# Clean up
rm ${ROOTFS_FN}

# Create a tar.gz of the rootfs
sudo tar -zcpf rootfs.tar.gz -C ./rootfs .
sudo chown "$(id -un)" rootfs.tar.gz

# Clean up
sudo rm -rf rootfs

# Create the distribution zip of WSL CentOS
mkdir out
mkdir dist
mv -f ${LNCR_FN} ./out/${LNCR_ZIPFN}
mv -f rootfs.tar.gz ./out/
pushd out
zip -r ../dist/CentOS${OS_VER}.zip ./*
popd

# Clean up
rm -rf out
```

I also maintain scripts for other CentOS versions, as well as ready-to-import `rootfs.tar.gz` files here: https://github.com/mishamosher/CentOS-WSL

Comment: Ugh! I like very much the approach of getting original files distributed from CentOS, but I don't understand everything in the script.  I will give both answers here a try, thank you very much!

Comment: @user10664542 You're welcome (: - In general, the script is quite simplistic. If there is anything specific, I can try my best to clarify it. As a side note, the QCOW2 CentOS images are more complete than the docker ones (they contain a more comprehensive list of preinstalled packages).

Comment: Looking at the script, it is not something that could be run under WSL2 itself (to extract the file system from .qcow2 creating rootfs.tar.  Is it possible to convert a .qcow2 to rootfs.tar under WSL2 itself?

Comment: The non-WSL-compatible (yet) commands are related to `modprobe` and `quemu-nbd`. There is no skipping those. Everything else runs pretty much on any Linux distro, DSL and OpenWRT included. You'll be better using Hyper-V or VitualBox with a small Linux box for these tasks, as they don't exhibit the WSL shortcomings.